# WiFi Printers All Disabled?

Tags: wifi, printer

My two WiFi printers show up but are listed as "Disabled".  I cannot find any way to enable them.  Any suggestions?  They work perfectly on my Linux Mint laptop.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have 1 wired Samsung CLX-3185 network printer and a HP wireless printer that comes up disabled also. Tried the about but did not work. I want to change from Win 10 and have tried many linux operating systems and I found this one the best for me and my family as I am new to Linux. What a great pity there is this bug (why dont they fix it) every thing else works for me but I guess I am back to Windows

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my WiFi Epson XP332. This is a wrong configured and delivered CUPS-problem. I solved it by changing the cups authorization in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`. I changed the most the settings to "order allow,deny".
Then you sholud be able to activate the printer in the settings menu or with 
`usr/sbin/cupsenable PRINTERNAME`. Maybe possible that you must reload the CUPS-daemon.

I think is a very huge bug. eOS is told to be user-friendly, so the printing must work out of the box. You cannot annoy new users with such a bitchy printer behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this on elementary OS 6.1, so the issue still remains 2.5 years after this question was asked.

One thing I noticed was that if I add my user to the `lpadmin` group then I can at least print. The printer still shows as Disabled in the System Settings Printers tool though.

To add yourself to the lpadmin group just do the following:

```
sudo adduser <YOURNAME> lpadmin
```

where `<YOURNAME>` is you account name. You then need to log out and back in again.

Using the CUPS web interface (`localhost:631`) I can manage the printer just fine after making this change too.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue with an HP ENVY 5000 series. It did start working temporarily and I managed to delete the printers marked disabled, but as soon as I ran system-config-printer to rename the Printer description, the disabled one returned. Incidentally you can add the printer using the CUPS web administration http://localhost:631/admin

Oddly I have 2 machines displaying this and they both appeared correctly after installing Thunderbird and Wordpress client, but both have since returned with a Printer listed as disabled. For me it is now just a cosmetic thing in the printer settings