# Canon WIFI printer disabled

Tags: release-hera, printer

I recently upgraded my EOS computer by installing **EOS Hera 5.1**. I did a normal install on the root directory "/" but kept everything else (other partitions like /home, /opt etc).

I have a printer/scanner combination here (*Canon PIXMA MG5750*) that I already used before with my previous EOS Loki.

After upgrading the computer, scanning works (connected via USB cable and with package *simple-scan*), but printing DOES NOT. It did work with Loki on the same computer. I have not moved any cable or reconfigured the printer or changed anything else but the EOS installation.

What's the concrete problem? When I switch on the printer and enter the settings screen printer, I see that my printer is correctly recognized (as *Canon MG5700 series*), but marked as disabled. I also cannot use it to print from a program (it does not show the printer in the printing submenus).

I checked the [only other similar question here on eos stackexchange](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17989/wifi-printers-all-disabled), but it did not help me. Maybe it's just something I don't understand about the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this problem by using a different printer setting. Instead of using what was offered via PlugnPlay, I manual did the "add printer" thing and used a driverless setting. It worked then. No idea why. But I thought I should post that in case it helps someone else.